# Visual Studio 2010 on Windows XP crashes suddenly then stops working until reinstall

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, crash, windows-xp

At work I use Visual Studio 2010 on Windows XP. The only extension installed was ASP.NET MVC 3 and the stuff bundled with it. For some reason VS works fine until it suddenly crashes, then it will crash when opening a file most of the time, and when it doesn't crash the Webserver process crashes when I try to run my MVC project from VS (with debug or not).
The first time this happened was when I was trying to look up online templates, then after it was reinstalled it worked fine until I included a JQuery library to the project. Running in safe mode doesn't seem to fix this and the logs don't say anything. 
Is there any way to stop VS from falling apart like this? I need to work on MVC 3 but I'm worried my boss looks bad at me since I'm the only one whose VS breaks down for no reason.

EDIT: This is the error I´m getting on ActivityLog.xml:

```
Construction of frame content failed. Frame identifier: ST:0:0:{eefa5220-e298-11d0-8f78-00a0c9110057} Frame caption: Propiedades Exception details: System.ArgumentException: La fuente 'Tahoma' no es compatible con el estilo 'Regular'. en System.Drawing.Font.CreateNativeFont() en System.Drawing.Font.Initialize(FontFamily family, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte gdiCharSet, Boolean gdiVerticalFont) en System.Drawing.Font..ctor(FontFamily family, Single emSize) en System.Drawing.SystemFonts.get_DefaultFont() en System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_DefaultFont() en System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Font() en System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.get_PreferredHeight() en System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.get_DefaultSize() en System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor(Boolean autoInstallSyncContext) en System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox..ctor() en Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.MSOComboBox..ctor(IUIService uiService) en Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.PBComboBox..ctor(IUIService uiService) en Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.PropertyBrowser.CreateUI() en Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.PropertyBrowser..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) en Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.PropertyBrowserService.get_PropertyBrowser() en Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.PropertyBrowserService.get_Window() en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.WindowPane.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIElementPane.CreateUIElementPane(Object& uiElement) en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.UIElementDocumentObject.Init(Boolean initSize) en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DocumentObjectSite.InitializeDocumentObject(Object punkView) en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.PropertyBrowserSwitcher.OnQuerySwitchPane(FrameMoniker frameMoniker) en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.ContextSwitchFrame.QuerySwitchPane(FrameMoniker frameMoniker) en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.ContextSwitchFrame.OnElementValueChanged(UInt32 elementid, Object varValueOld, Object varValueNew) en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.ContextSwitchFrame.OnToolWindowCreated() en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.PropertyBrowserSwitcher.OnToolWindowCreated() en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool) en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.FindToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, Boolean create, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool) en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsToolWindowFactory.CreateToolWindow(Guid& toolWindowType, UInt32 id) en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that VS couldn´t find Tahoma regular. I fixed the problem by reinstalling Tahoma.

Answer (score 0):

Watch here

http://www.visualstudio.com/it-it/products/visual-studio-ultimate-with-msdn-vs#Fragment_SystemRequirements

You can use Visual Studio 2010 without problem on Windows XP (with SP3), since it is an officially supported OS (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=133421).

However, in order to develop personal opinion WinXp is too outdated ... but you know that already:-)